# How to get the page slug of the current archive page for a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have  a custom post type and custom taxonomy. The taxonomy works like a category system. Users can add the custom posts to the  categories. There is one page per each category, displaying the posts in that category.

I need to get the page slug of the current category page. How can I do this please?

For example, my url is: `?event-categories=day-courses`.

event-categories is the custom taxonomy.

This code would work if I only had 'day-courses' in this custom taxonomy, which I do not:

```
<?php
 global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
    echo $post_slug; 

$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'event',  'event-categories' => 'day-courses' ) );
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>
<div>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at get_query_var($custom_taxonomy_slug); http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: What do you mean by the page slug?  If the page is for a category, it'd have multiple posts on there.  Are you looking for the taxonomy term slug?

Comment: @MannyFleurmond Yes, that's it!

Comment: Is there any reason you are creating a custom query?

Comment: @MannyFleurmond Yes, my custom taxonomy acts like a category system, with posts from my custom post type associated with it. I want to display all the posts associated with each 'category' on separate pages

Comment: You don't need a custom query for that.  All you would have to do is create a new template file with the name of `taxonomy-event-categories.php` and you can use the main loop instead of creating your own.  I'd also rename your taxonomy to `event_categories` since having the dashes in the taxonomy name may cause issues when you do create an archive page

Comment: @MannyFleurmond I've got this code in my taxonomy-even-categories.php .  I have got moe than one 'category' in my custom taxonomy. I want to display only the posts that are associated with e.g. day courses on the day course category page. Then have another page to display family courses with posts associated with that category all on one page. I need to get the current taxonomy page category so I can do this. So I can display all posts belonging to one category in this taxonomy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your current code:

```
$tax_slug = get_query_var( 'event-categories' );
```

Comment: Thank-you, that's what I think I need!I have put `$tax_slug` in `$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'event',  'event-categories' => '$tax_slug' ) );` but it doesn't seem to work? Any ideas please?

Comment: See my new answer and use that instead

Comment: Thank-you Manny, you are my hero right now. Really up against time, and this is the 1st website I have worked on. Have a good  day/evening!

Comment: I recommend that you dome some research into template file hierarchy: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display .  Although my answer worked, how you are doing your template would be easier if you let WordPress handle the taxonomy stuff and use the main loop.